# ForkJoinPool using more CPU than specified

Tags: java, fork-join, forkjoinpool

I set up a ForkJoinPool to use half of my CPUs like this:

```
ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(
        Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() / 2);
```

However, when I submit a job such as the merge sort described [there](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/java-mergesort-using-forkjoin-framework.html), the pool is using up to 80+% of my machine CPUs.

Is this something expected? If so, is there a way to effectively restrict the number of working threads?

Comment: How do you calculate or find the "80+%" usage?

Comment: This is the value reported by my system monitor / top.

Comment: On linux by default, top gives the CPU usage as a % of one CPU - so in your case you would be using 80% of one cpu, not 80% of all your CPUs.

Comment: Actually my system monitor references the percentage relative to the total CPUs available. So on my 12 cores computer, top reports 1000% CPU usage.

Answer (score 1):

The excessive thread problem goes back to early Java7. You did not specify which version you're using, but no matter, both Java7 and Java8 have similar problems with excessive threads. Java8u40 addressed some of the excessive problems in nested calls, but at the expense of excessive spinning.

I've been writing a continuing critique of this framework since 2011. The article for Java8 is [here](http://coopsoft.com/ar/Calamity2Article.html) There are links to both the first (Java7) and 8u40 articles therein.

To specifically answer your question: There is no way to restrict the use of work threads with this framework.

Comment: Interesting article. I am actually using Java8u40 (OpenJDK).

Comment: You can try  using the CountedCompleter class. It doesn't use join() so you may get better results. That is, if you can figure out  how to use it.